# Difference between OLS and GLS linear Regression in data with heteroscedasticity

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

I have a cross sectional model which displays heteroscedasticity. I've tried a GLS regression and an OLS with heteroscedasticity-consistent standard errors linear regression. They give significantly different results, and I'm not sure which model is more appropriate.

When should I use GLS over OLS or vice versa?

If it's helpful, the data is here: https://github.com/Robdei/Blood-Donation-Simulation/blob/master/Results%20Final.xlsx

specifically, it's a regression of number of 'infections from transfusion' onto 'platelets/person' and 'MSM excluded'

[image: Here are the regression statistics]

Comment: Could you post more about your two regressions?

Comment: Absolutely, I just added an image of all of the regression statistics. Tell me if you need more. As my badge says, I'm a new contributor.

Comment: The difference are so big such that I believe two different models were fit. But I do not know anything about sm.GLS and smf.ols, and did not find anything from internet. So it seems I cannot help you.

Comment: This is in Python, and sm and smf are directories of the statsmodel package. Here are the logs for both. https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.GLS.html

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html

Comment: If you look at that skew and kurtosis, it looks like you have some outliers.  Given that, the GLS estimates are likely to be affected even more than your heteroskedasticity-adjusted OLS as the estimate of the covariance matrix provides another avenue for outliers to influence the estimates.   I'm not going to look at the data, at least not now, but that's where I would start.

Comment: The results are too different. Can you tell us how you specified the variance covariance matrix in GLS? What are the contents of `sigma`? Your model degrees of freedom should exceed 2 with GLS in my opinion. It appears you have huge skew and kurtosis. Based on some simulation I've done, GLS performs better with normal errors. Without more information, my first instinct is that the GLS specification is not correct.

Comment: Yes, the covariance matrix is specified as such:

ols_resid = sm.OLS(Transmissions, Exog).fit().resid
res_fit = sm.OLS(ols_resid[1:], ols_resid[:-1]).fit()
rho = res_fit.params
order = toeplitz(np.arange(len(Transmissions)))
sigma = rho**order

1) take an ols regression of the original data
2) take an ols regression of the residuals of the last regressions
3) multiply the coefficient of the former regression by a toeplitz matrix of appropriate size